# How to eliminate relay buzzing when turning on and off

Tags: relay, pwm, automotive, 12v, buzzing

I'm using [one of these relays](https://AEDIKO%204pcs%20DC%2012V%20Relay%20Module%201%20Channel%20Relay%20Board%20with%20Optocoupler%20Isolation%20Support%20High%20or%20Low%20Level%20https://a.co/d/fh7SPtK) to power some LED's using a trigger wire that outputs either 0V, 50mV, or 12V.  The relay has a low voltage trigger setting that turns on when there is anything less than 4V, and off when there is 0V or 12V.

The problem I'm having is that when the signal changes from 0V to 50mV or from 50mV to 12V and vice versa, it does so via PWM, which causes a temporary buzzing as the relay turns on or off.

I'm pretty sure I could eliminate this with the use of a strategically placed capacitor, but I'm not sure where to put it in the circuit or what size to use.  That is where I could use some help.

[Here is a video that shows what I'm doing.](https://youtu.be/3Sa2FlABE0k?si=OzuUUIpw6damqrNZ)

Comment: @MicroservicesOnDDD Any thoughts?